# Adding genres and themes from work

Tags: javascript, meteor, cyclomatic-complexity

Codacy is telling me this method has a complexity of 13. I need some tips on how to reduce it, more specifically inside the `forEach` loop.

I've already changed it from an `if/`else` if hell, but it seems it wasn't enough.

```
function addGenresAndThemesFromWork(work){
    let workDetails = {workId: work.$.id, genres: [], themes: []};
    let workInfo = work.info;

    if (typeof workInfo === 'object') {
        Object.keys(workInfo).forEach(function (key) {
            let workfInfoType = workInfo[key].$.type;
            let workInfoValue = workInfo[key]._;

            switch (workfInfoType.toLowerCase()) {
                case 'genres':
                    workDetails.genres.push(workInfoValue);
                    if (Genres.findOne({name: workInfoValue}) === undefined) {
                        Genres.insert({
                            name: workInfoValue
                        });
                    }
                    break;
                case 'themes':
                    workDetails.themes.push(workInfoValue);
                    if (Themes.findOne({name: workInfoValue.toLowerCase()}) === undefined) {
                        Themes.insert({
                            name: workInfoValue.toLowerCase()
                        });
                    }
                    break;
                case 'main title':
                    workDetails.name = workInfoValue;
                    break;
                case 'plot summary':
                    workDetails.plot = workInfoValue;
                    break;
                case 'objectionable content':
                    if (workInfoValue.toLowerCase() === 'ma') {
                        workDetails.mature = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'picture':
                    let workImg = workInfo[key].img[1];
                    if (workImg !== undefined) {
                        workDetails.picture = workImg.$;
                    } else {
                        if (workInfo[key].img[0] !== undefined) {
                            workDetails.picture = workInfo[key].img[0].$;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 'alternative title':
                    if (workInfo[key].$.lang.toLowerCase() === 'ja') {
                        workDetails.alternativeTitle = workInfoValue;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        });
    }

    if (!_.has(workDetails, 'picture')) {
        workDetails.picture = {src: '/default.jpg', temporary: true};
    }

    persistWorkDetails(workDetails);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a tool here to count, so I don't know how the numbers will
play out.  That said, I agree with the interpretation since there's a
lot of things going on here and it makes sense to detangle the function
into smaller bits.

The big `if` block immediately suggests that some kind of
short-circuiting or decomposing into functions would be useful.  E.g. if
`workInfo` is not an object, call `persistWOrkDetails` and just return;
the other branch will continue afterwards and also persists the object.

Then again, I'd rather split a function off in this case, though I have
no idea what to call it.

```
function addGenresAndThemesFromWork(work) {
    let workDetails = {workId: work.$.id, genres: [], themes: []};

    if (typeof work.info === 'object') {
        fillInWorkDetails(work.info, workDetails);
    }

    if (!_.has(workDetails, 'picture')) {
        workDetails.picture = {src: '/default.jpg', temporary: true};
    }

    persistWorkDetails(workDetails);
}
```

Next up are the genres and themes, which exhibit a common pattern, so
again, move that into a separate function.  Sounds like that is a
function that might already exist in a library anyway.

```
function pushNew(thing, name) {
    let value = {name: name};

    if (thing.findOne(value) === undefined) {
        thing.insert({name: name});
    }
}

...

case 'genres':
    workDetails.genres.push(workInfoValue);
    pushNew(Genres, workInfoValue);
    break;
case 'themes':
    workDetails.themes.push(workInfoValue);
    pushNew(Themes, workInfoValue.toLowerCase());
    break;
```

For "objectionable content" (I wonder) the `if` can be replaced with an
or, that is:

```
workDetails.mature = workDetails.mature || workInfoValue.toLowerCase() === 'ma';
```

The syntax is a bit longer, but a temporary variable could be used to
deal with that.

- Is there a particular reason to use `Object.keys` instead of `for
  ... in` on the `workInfo` object?
- The nested `else { if ... }` can just be written as `else if` in this
  case.
- `workInfo[key]` appears way too often, just assign it to a shorter
  name.
- Since you create `workDetails` yourself, you probably don't have to
  use `_.has`, but just plain `in`.
- The `picture` default value can be moved into the `workDetails`
  initialisation since the loop will *always* overwrite the existing
  value.  That also takes care of any possible issues with `undefined`.
- If a function (like `findOne`) only returns a false value if couldn't
  find something, then the comparison can also simply be `if
  (!findOne(...))` - I'm assuming that that's done for a reason though.

With all that in mind I'm arriving at the following, which, depending on
the exact format and semantics of the objects could be further
distilled, but I think this is good enough for now and for you to
continue on it later.

I'd also suggest that the `workDetails` object is filled in with more
defaults so it's actually clear that e.g. a missing `mature` field
actually means the same as `mature: false` in the initialisation (or
not, in which case the code below is slightly wrong).

```
function pushNew(thing, name) {
    let value = {name: name};

    if (thing.findOne(value) === undefined) {
        thing.insert(value);
    }
}

function pictureValue(img) {
    if (img[1] !== undefined) {
        return img[1].$;
    } else if (img[0] !== undefined) {
        return img[0].$;
    }
    return undefined;
}

function fillInWorkDetails(workInfo, workDetails) {
    for (let key in workInfo) {
        let value = workInfo[key];
        let workInfoValue = workInfo[key]._;

        switch (value.$.type.toLowerCase()) {
            case 'genres':
                workDetails.genres.push(workInfoValue);
                pushNew(Genres, workInfoValue);
                break;
            case 'themes':
                workDetails.themes.push(workInfoValue);
                pushNew(Themes, workInfoValue.toLowerCase());
                break;
            case 'main title':
                workDetails.name = workInfoValue;
                break;
            case 'plot summary':
                workDetails.plot = workInfoValue;
                break;
            case 'objectionable content':
                workDetails.mature = workDetails.mature || workInfoValue.toLowerCase() === 'ma';
                break;
            case 'picture':
                workDetails.picture = pictureValue(value.img) || workDetails.picture;
                break;
            case 'alternative title':
                if (value.$.lang.toLowerCase() === 'ja') {
                    workDetails.alternativeTitle = workInfoValue;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    return workDetails;
}

function addGenresAndThemesFromWork(work) {
    let workDetails = {
        workId: work.$.id,
        genres: [],
        themes: [],
        picture: {src: '/default.jpg', temporary: true}
    };

    if (typeof work.info === 'object') {
        fillInWorkDetails(work.info, workDetails);
    }

    persistWorkDetails(workDetails);
}
```